# Getting Server Error in '/' Application while scraping asp page in Python

Tags: python

My code:

```
import requests
import os
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx'
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
r = requests.get(url, cookies=jar)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

view_state = soup.find(id ="__VIEWSTATE")




headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Referer":"http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx"}

payload = {"__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkDownload", "__EVENTARGUMENT": "","__VIEWSTATE":view_state,"__EVENTVALIDATION":"g8vXAQKJsYefCgK6rpDlDwL8np6XAwLl44LQAgK0w8TlCwKHlNXODQKW0sv1BgLei4rQAwKExL/8BQLJsJHgCQLhsb3hCQLJsLmaCAL40JWiCgK9vIn8DA==",
"myDestination1":"#","WINDOW_NAMER":"1","myDestination":"#","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fmdate":"20131003","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$eddate":"20131009",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdnCode":"","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDate":"","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTodate":"","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$hdnCode":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$smartSearch":"","ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlregulation":"ALL"}

r = requests.post(url,cookies=jar,headers=headers,data=payload)
print r.content
```

What I'm attempting to do is download a csv file from the url above but getting an error as mentioned in the question.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is nothing wrong with your request. I tried your code and got the same error.

The error that you see is a common error for services written in ASP. It almost always means there is a configuration issue at the server end. Google the error and you will see a number of hits with possible solutions, none of which work for you since you do not own that service.

Are you sure you have the correct base url? Is there an example of the service usage on BSE India?

Comment: - 1. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Games Thanks for being the SO police. What would we fo without you